# quill.formatText() won't allow nested formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text-editor, quill

I'm using `quill.formatText()` to add a custom "highlight" format to my text editor.  I extended a Blot like so:

```
let Inline = Quill.import('blots/inline');
class highlight extends Inline {
    static create() {
      return super.create();
    }

    static formats() {
      return true;
    }
}
highlight.blotName = 'highlight';
highlight.className = 'highlight';
highlight.tagName = 'span';
Quill.register(highlight);
```

I then call `quill.formatText(start, selectionLength, 'highlight', true);`, which wraps my selection in a `<span class="highlight">` tag.  So far so good.

The trouble is, I want each selection to be wrapped in its own `span` tag.  When I make two selections to the text, one inside the other, only the outer `span` remains.

For example, with the text `test inside text`. If I highlight the whole string in addition to just the word `inside`, I'd expect to get:

`<span class="highlight">Test <span class="highlight">inside</span> text</span>`

Whereas I actually get:

`<span class="highlight">Test inside text</span>`

It seems like this is an optimization that QuillJS is doing behind the scenes - is there anyway I can turn it off, so that I can keep both nested `span`s?

Comment: Also, for the record, making two disjoint highlights preserves both of the the `span`s just fine.  It's only when they intersect or nest that Quill decides to optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the format just true or false, try making it some kind of id that identifies the use case. You can then either add a data attribute to the span to hold the id, or create a unique class like in your comments.

You might find this Pull Request on quill helpful in getting to a solution that will work for you (or just use this code directly)

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/pull/1217

Comment: Hi Rik, that's exactly what I'm looking for.  The code in that PR looks pretty straightforward, so I should be able to finagle it for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a mere optimization--it is necessary for the determinism Quill guarantees. If you have some text "Test inside text" and say it is bolded, Quill guarantees the output is `<strong>Test inside text</strong>`, not `<strong>Test inside </strong><strong>text</strong>` or `<strong>Test <strong>inside</strong> text</strong>` or the infinite number of HTML legal options.

Quill is designed to be unambiguous so you can either remove ambiguity from your design, or use an editor that allows for it.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the reply.  I understand why the mechanism is in place to prevent invalid HTML, but the example of the `span`s above is perfectly valid and unambiguous.  Adding arbitrary `span` tags was the point of using a custom Blot - for example, if there is some text that's enclosed in two "highlight" classes rather than just one, it should display darker, be independently clickable, etc.  If there's not a way to "turn off" that determinism, so to speak, is there any other way to accomplish this?  I'm only inserting these highlights in `readOnly` mode.

Comment: No the example I posted is perfectly legal HTML. But it is ambiguous, as is your example, which is the problem.

Comment: I see.  In that case, would there be a recommended way to change the `className` of my custom "highlight" Blot?  So that in `quill.formatText()` I could pass in, for example, an extra parameter like so:  `quill.formatText(start, length, 'highlight', 2, true);` and then logic somewhere in the Blot to make the className "highlight-2".  That way I could make "highlight-1", "highlight-2", etc. spans that wouldn't interfere and get merged.  I realize that isn't the actual syntax of `formatText`, but I don't have a solid enough understanding of Blots to know if something like that would be possible.